# "other linker flag" settings not being saved

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-flags

I am required to enter in `-ObjC` into the "other linker flags" area for my app as I use admob. I have been doing this with no problems in other apps, but in my latest app if i close xcode at all the flag will disappear.

To be specific, i enter in `-ObjC` into the "other linker flag" area and it's there, i run it without issue. When i reload the project or reload xcode, this area is now blank again and my app crashes until i re-add the flag.

I tend to think there is something that is not allowing write access?

I have also tried deleting all the current builds as well which didn't fix it.

Edit - FOUND SOLUTION: Something in the directory was "locked" and from the command prompt I executed the command "sudo chmod 777" on the whole directory. This fixed the issue

Comment: Highlight the field and hit enter to bring up a popover.  Click the + and add it in there.

Comment: Yeah I have tried it that way too, and entering them in one by one (for debug, release and distribution) as well and it keeps resetting.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing overwriting your project files?  SCM or some such?